# generating GUI for C++ code

Tags: qt, visual-c++

i need to generate a GUI for a ready code written with C++ the code is divided into some classes containing one that represent user interface to facilitate generating GUI without big modifications on my code

and i already designed the GUI window using QT Designer

now i want to link both logical part (my classes)and GUI part(QT Designer output class) ,how to add all classes to the GUI,how to handle signals coming from GUI  and send the appropriate input to the logical part

GUI

- get some words from user
- get slider input as an int
- add files from HDD (logical part need full paths)
- out some text

NOTE:first time with QT

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start with these simple tutorials

http://www.qttutorial.com/qt/hello-qt-your-first-application/

http://www.qttutorial.com/qt/hello-qt-your-first-qt-application-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

I you need a really simple solution - call this in desired order:

```
 QInputDialog::getText();
 QInputDialog::getInt();
 QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();
 QMessageBox::information();
```

QtAssistant should give you much more details and examples.